# Why does this basic webpack hot module replacement work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I tried the very basic HMR(without react-hot-loader) using webpack after reading this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/hot-reloading-in-react-1140438583bf) by Dan Abramov.

**Entry `index.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

if(module.hot) {
  // Basic HMR for React without using react-loader

  // module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
  //   const UpdatedApp = require('./App').default;
  //
  //   render(<UpdatedApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
  // });

  // Why does this work as well?
  module.hot.accept();
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**The webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/js/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true
  }
}
```

My question is that, why does HMR for React app works with just `module.hot.accept()`?

As per my understanding, webpack's HMR only provides a simple API to detect changes in files. How to handle those changes depends on the loaders. The style-loader handles `.css` files. And, in context of a React app, the changes to `.js` modules might be managed by react-hot-loader.

Or, as per the [Medium post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/hot-reloading-in-react-1140438583bf), one can manage them like this:

```
render(<UpdatedApp />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

So why just doing `module.hot.accept()` gives same result as doing `render(<UpdatedApp />, document.getElementById('app'))`?

**Package verisons**

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
```

Comment: Does it still work if you're using forms or other internal state?

Comment: @Kaspars I am not considering preserving internal state. Just don't want the browser to refresh(it does when we don't opt-in for HMR at all).  I don't understand how webpack's `module.hot.accept()` is able to manage the React rendering logic thing.